# How do I control the volume with a non-Mac keyboard?

Tags: mac, keyboard

I just bought an iMac with a bluetooth keyboard. The F keys were brilliantly working to control the volume, but then I exchanged it for a wired keyboard to save batteries. Now my F keys have their old functions, and they don't adjust volume, toggle Spaces, etc.

The problem is not fixed by System Preferences → Keyboard → Toggle switch.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's toggle switch? *Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys*?

Comment: Great news!  I have one of the brand new SteelSeries Apex pro keyboards (the "first adjustable keystroke" keyboards) .. apart from being an astounding keyboard, yes, the novelty scroll wheel at the top right **DOES** adjust the **master** volume of the macbook.  Dunno how they did it but it works.

Comment: Had the same problem and I solved it via [karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/). Works with macOs Catalina.

Answer (score 19):

For the Mac Googlers out there with PC keyboards, I highly recommend the free app [Spark](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14352/spark) for controlling volume via shortcuts. I currently use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>/<kbd>W</kbd>/<kbd>E</kbd> to control Down/Up/Mute on my keyboard.

Comment: I use ... volume-down: Cmd + [   ...  volume-up: Cmd + ]   ...  volume-mute: Cmd + \   ... same in windows for my mechanical keyboard (winkey)

Comment: Link seems dead :(

Comment: Link still works for me.

Comment: Link works, but I don't see anyway to download it now and it says the app has been discontinued.

Comment: Can somebody tell me how to use it?

Answer (score 10):

My best understanding so far is that there is no way to replicate the system-wide volume behavior of the built-in function keys using the keyboard properties window.  I think you must have a mac keyboard or one designed to be used with a Mac.

If you're willing to use a third-party app to get the effect you want, then try the one suggested above.

Comment: Chris, you're right, I've never found a way to adjust the **master** volume externally.  But now I did!  Surprisingly the brand-new apex pro keyboard, I had it plugged in for a week and thought "I wonder what spinning the wheel here does" -  happily it DOES adjust the true master volume on the macbook.  Hooray!

Comment: You correctly get the on-screen graphic and everything. Absolutely no software installs.  Hooray!

Comment: To all users of stackexchange: Please don't use references as "the answer above" because answers change order based on rating and maybe other stats.

Answer (score 9):

Keyboard Maestro did the trick for me. Just add a global hotkey and search for volume under actions. Super simple. I mapped my volume to command-shift-up/down. Seems to be working without conflict as far as I can tell.

Comment: thank you so much

Answer (score 5):

You can configure all of these things in System Preferences. For things like Spaces and Exposé, I believe the settings are under System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Exposé & Spaces if you are on Leopard or Snow Leopard. On Lion they are in System Preferences → Mission Control.

For things like adjusting volume, there are likely already shortcuts in iTunes (e.g. ⌘↑ and ⌘↓ for volume). You can also add custom Keyboard Shortcuts for any menu item in any application (or in all applications). Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts → Application Shortcuts. Add a new shortcut, choose iTunes.app for the Application, enter the exact Menu Title (e.g. "Increase Volume"), and enter the shortcut you'd like.

Comment: Question is about global shortcuts and your answer is works only from itunes or music app.

Comment: Similarly you can use ⌘↑ and ⌘↓ to adjust volume in Spotify

Answer (score 1):

Edit (2022-08-18): As noted in the comments, this approach is not totally reliable. Leaving the answer for completeness, the approach is not recommended.

Another option is to use Apple Automator (AppleScript) scripts. Source: [Media Keys In OSX For Any Keyboard](https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2011/10/media-keys-in-osx-for-any-keyboard.html) by [Grant Skinner](https://www.gskinner.com/).

For example, here is a [volume up script](https://blog.gskinner.com/blog/assets/MediaControlScripts.zip):

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set vol to ((output volume of (get volume settings)) + 5)
    if (vol > 100) then set vol to 100
    set volume output volume (vol)
end run
```

You can download a variety of [scripts](https://blog.gskinner.com/blog/assets/MediaControlScripts.zip) for Volume Up, Volume Down, Mute and more from [the original blog post](https://blog.gskinner.com/archives/2011/10/media-keys-in-osx-for-any-keyboard.html).

Double-click each script to "install" it. This will add the script to `System Preferences > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts -> Services`. From there, you can map key bindings to each script.

For example, here are my key bindings:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts]

*Note that this solution does not work when some applications are in focus. For example, I found that when the Calculator app was in focus the key bindings were blocked, no matter which bindings I chose.*

Comment: I got this to work, but it is not super reliable. It reacts slowly because the workflows have to run when you hit the keyboard shortcut. You will see this as a spinning cogwheel in the mac menu bar. As Keith hinted at it does not work in all applications, i.e. if the application you are using does not have a "Services" submenu in its menu then this does not work.

Comment: @stefansundin I also eventually gave up on this approach. Like you said, it is too slow and doesn't work in all applications.

Answer (score 0):

I created 3 Apple Shortcuts:

1. [Mute/Unmute](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/e3fb76c389294e16a59cb0027e831eeb) -> Ctrl+F10
2. [Reduce Volume](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/0a1d609633ee4a4b98fe751f67c035cc) -> Ctrl+F11
3. [Increase Volume](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/7515f2f12b764e438ae9f83153e7211f) -> Ctrl+F12

In order to assign a keyboard shortcut to them, click the info button on the top right, then in the Details panel click on the `Add Keyboard Shortcut` button.

Hope this helps!

Edit: here is the Apple Script used for the first shortcut:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if output muted of (get volume settings) is false then
        set volume with output muted
    else
        set volume without output muted
    end if
    return input
end run
```

Comment: I am not sure how we can verify the contents of these scripts for safety/trustworthiness. I recommend that you include the content of the Apple Scripts you're sharing, so those who are less inclined to download and run random things online can recreate what you've done.

Comment: Sure, thanks! I didn't know that by sharing them, the content of them would be hidden, sorry about that.