# How do I control the volume with a non-Mac keyboard? [answer below]

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts

Reposting [How do I control the volume with a non-Mac keyboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/319396/how-do-i-control-the-volume-with-a-non-mac-keyboard) to answer since I don't have 10 reputation.